# Casting boxed byte

Tags: c#, casting

I'm trying to write an extension method that, given a value, will return

- The value itself if it's different from `DBNull.Value`
- The default value for `value`'s type

Yeah, that's not the clearest explanation, maybe some code will make what I'm trying to accomplish obvious.

```
public static T GetValueOrDefault<T>(this object value) {
    if (value == DBNull.Value)
        return default(T);
    else
        return (T)value;
}
```

As long as `value`'s boxed type is the same as `T`, this method works correctly.

The real fun kicks in when the types are different, for instance the boxed value is `byte` and `T` is `int`.

Is there an elegant way to make this work?

Doing some typechecking manually to first cast from e.g. `object` to `byte` and then from `byte` to `T`, of course, won't work.

**Edit**

The proposed solution should work with enums too, not only with "standard" types.

Comment: This won't compile, `default()` requires a `Type` parameter, not a value. And can you show some sample code how you would like to achieve this?

Comment: I just assumed the OP meant to write `default(T)`.

Comment: @CodeCaster Christian Hayter is right. Sorry, my bad. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call your method with a type argument that exactly matches the database value, then cast it to what you actually want, e.g.

```
int result = (int) row["NullableByteColumn"].GetValueOrDefault<byte>();
```

I think this is reasonable because the code clearly separates the two different concepts that are at work here:

- Reading a database value into the correct equivalent .NET data type.
- Mapping the database access layer type into the required business logic layer type.

This separation of responsibility becomes more important if the required data type is something further removed from `int` and requires more complex translation, e.g. an enum, a string, or a day offset from a date.

Comment: Thanks Christian, that's what I ended up doing before I posted the question. I was just wondering if there was a way to abstract the type cast away from the client code, or if doing that was acceptable.

Comment: I'm sure it's possible to abstract the cast away, but in my opinion that is not ideal because it hides the intent of the code.

Comment: Thanks, I tend to agree. I'll accept this answer in a few hours, unless someone posts something groundbreaking.

Answer (score 2):

```
    public static T GetValueOrDefault<T>(this object value) {
        if (value == DBNull.Value) {
            return default(T);
        }
        else {
            if (typeof(T).IsEnum) value = Enum.ToObject(typeof(T), Convert.ToInt64(value));
            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
        }
    }
```

Comment: I might be doing something wrong, but this doesn't seem to work for me, it throws an `InvalidCastException`.

Comment: Hmm, hard to guess what the types of value and T are, don't make us guess.

Comment: In my code I'm dealing with enums too, and with enums it doesn't work (while it works like a charm for the `byte` to `int` case).

Comment: Yes, enums are difficult to cast due to their underlying type.  Post updated.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Byte myByte = 5;

        object myObject = (object)myByte;

        int myInt = myObject.GetValueOrDefault<Byte>();
        Console.WriteLine(myInt); // 5

        myObject = DBNull.Value;

        myInt = myObject.GetValueOrDefault<Byte>();
        Console.WriteLine(myInt); // 0

        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}

public static class ObjectExtension
{
    public static T GetValueOrDefault<T>(this object value)
    {
        if (value == DBNull.Value)
        {
            return default(T);
        }
        else
        {
            return (T)value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And it works for me, too. But I came up with a counterexample (straight from the code I'm working with). Instead of a `byte` variable, try declaring a `DataTable`, adding a column and a row (containing `(byte) 5`), and then `int myInt = dt.Rows[0]["foo"].GetValueOrDefault<int>();`. The way in which the two examples differ eludes me, I'll admit.